# .NET Core 2.1 Add System.Web.Services

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to upgrade an ASMX web service from .NET 4.5 to .NET Core 2.1. Are ASMX web services compatible? If so, how do I add the assembly reference?

The type or namespace name 'Services' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: There is no migration path for such. Rewrite it.

Comment: Simply stating to rewrite it is not always an option. I have been asked to start migrating enterprise applications to the new .Net Core standard, but because one of the 3rd Party .dll files that I reference uses System.Web.Services I keep getting a reference not found error.

Answer (score 0):

You can still *consume* SOAP services by adding a "Connected Service" using the Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider in Visual Studio and it will generate a `Reference.cs` file with a C# proxy to the webservice.  It is correct that the `System.Web` namespace is missing, it is not available in .NET Core. You'll have to rewrite code using it.

*Creating* ASMX webservices is deprecated though and not supported in ASP.NET Core. You should rewrite it to an ASP.NET Core Web API. Please take a look here to get started: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1.